# Input type="search" not showing background color in Safari

Tags: css

Seach input is looking fine in all browser except safari. background color is not working in search input in safari. please solve this problem

Comment: We will solve it. We simply require your code :)

Comment: A code example please.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add:

```
[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
```